# Why is this plist read/write failing?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm following along an iOS tutorial and I've run into trouble with plists. I have this code for a reflection, a model object in my app:

```
struct Reflection {
let title: String
let body: String
let author: String
let favorite: Bool
let creationDate: Date
let id: UUID
}

extension Reflection {
var plistRepresentation: [String: AnyObject] {
    return [
        "title": title as AnyObject,
        "body": body as AnyObject,
        "author": author as AnyObject,
        "favorite": favorite as AnyObject,
        "creationDate": creationDate as AnyObject,
        "id": id as AnyObject
    ]
}

init(plist: [String: AnyObject]) {
    title = plist["title"] as! String
    body = plist["body"] as! String
    author = plist["author"] as! String
    favorite = plist["favorite"] as! Bool
    creationDate = plist["creationDate"] as! Date
    id = plist["id"] as! UUID
}
}
```

Then I have this storage controller:

```
class StorageController {
fileprivate let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default
    .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    .first!

fileprivate var notesFileURL: URL {
    return documentsDirectoryURL
        .appendingPathComponent("Notes")
        .appendingPathExtension("plist")
}

func save(_ notes: [Reflection]) {
    let notesPlist = notes.map { $0.plistRepresentation } as NSArray
    notesPlist.write(to: notesFileURL, atomically: true)
}

func fetchNotes() -> [Reflection] {

    guard let notePlists = NSArray(contentsOf: notesFileURL) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
        print("No notes")
        return []
    }
    print("Notes found")
    return notePlists.map(Reflection.init(plist:))
}
}
```

I get no errors when I call `save()` and it attempts to write to the plist. However, when I call `fetchNotes()` it prints "No Notes", implying that the array using those contents is nil or that it cannot be cast to a dictionary. Why would this be?

Comment: What about using `init(contentsOf url: URL, error: ()) throws` that throws an `error` with a try/catch? Maybe some info there. Also, forcing a cast (`as ! [[String:AnyObject]]` might log something).

Comment: This seems to be a very bad or outdated tutorial. The recommended way to read and write property lists is `PropertyListSerialization` – which provides good error handling – and the object values are `Any` not `AnyObject`. In Swift 4 you can even use the `Codable` protocol and `PropertyListEn-/Decoder` which would reduce the code in the struct to the property declaration lines.

Comment: @vadian Will look into that. Following The Ultimate Course to Making Professional iOS Apps by Matteo Manferdini. It seems to be very updated...

Comment: The type `[String:AnyObject]` for a property list dictionary is inappropriate in Swift 3+. All property list types are value types (`Any`). This avoids also the ugly bridge casts to `AnyObject`

Answer (score 3):

A `UUID` is not a valid element of a property list. You need to store it as a string in the property list, e.g.

```
“id”: id.uuidString as AnyObject
```

and convert it back like this:

```
id = UUID(uuidString: plist[“id”] as! String)!
```